# Where can I run into pitfalls when using an Android emulator over a real device for app development?

Tags: android, android-emulator, development-environment

I want to get into developing apps for Android because of its large userbase. However, at the moment I do not have a smartphone. I'm also not too keen on getting an Android phone in the future.

What problems could I encounter when developing apps for Android solely using an emulator? I could use my parents' Android phones for the occasional testing, but will an emulator prove sufficient otherwise? Furthermore, is it possible to set up an Android Virtual Device with low-end hardware on my computer to test out apps with low-end phones?

note0: I do not plan on developing apps which require use of the phone's sensors (such as gyros, GPS, etc.) I only plan on developing apps which require internet access for API calls and perhaps microphone usage (I can't give away too many details right now ;) )

note1: I know this question has been asked before on stackoverflow (albeit 4 years ago). However, I feel it is important to revisit the question because emulators, hardware, and Android itself have changed enormously in the last few years.

edit: My main issues are problems like the app looking weird on the phone despite it looking fine on the emulator or working slowly on the phone but working fine on the emulator. Will every app which works fine on the emulator work fine on the phone as well with a similar hardware configuration as the emulator? I'm in particular targetting devices with Android 4.x/5.x.

Comment: guys! What the heck! What's the -1 for? Also, I'm using a much faster computer than the one in the linked question, so that doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Without a doubt, the biggest problem is that many functions like push
  notifications, maps, geo-location, in-app vending etc. cannot be
  tested with an emulator. The reason is that all these functions are
  present in the Google Play Services library which is not present on
  emulators.
- Another important reason for testing on hardware devices is that the
  OS implementation is changed by manufacturers like Samsung, HTC and
  others, and therefore, certain problems & exceptions are not observed
  till a real device is used.
- But the most important reason has to be that running apps on an
  actual phone is a hell of a lot more fun that it is with the painfully
  slow and retarded emulators! One of the most important things about
  Android is that anybody with an Android phone can easily explore
  computer science concepts by running simple programs on their phone.
  It is incredibly easy, even for a novice, to just fire up their
  Android device and start exploring the world of programming! Till just a few years back, it was incredibly difficult to debug an app on a `Symbian` or `Palm` or `WinCE` device. `iOS` is still as retarded when it comes to running the simplest apps, you have to create a provisioning profile to run a Hello World app on an iPhone!

**EDIT:**

- If your processor supports Intel virtualization, then the emulator can be made to run as fast as a real device. You need to check that out. If your PC is *low-end* in the sense that it does not support such virtualization, then running and testing Android apps will be a painful, tedious experience that will suck all the fun out of the development process.
- Emulators do have *one* significant advantage over real devices - an emulator is able to access web services on a `localhost`. If you are still in development phase on your local server and have not yet shifted to a publicly hosted environment, the emulator can easily access web services on a local server. All you have to do is put your computer on the same network as the local server and you're good to go. A real device cannot access a `localhost`; its impossible, as far as I know.
- The Android emulator is a true *emulator* - it emulates sensors as well, so in fact you *can* test sensor programming (with some limitations) on an emulator. It cannot do things like GPS, maps etc. because those features have been migrated to the Google Play Services library, and they require a valid Google account to be used, which is why that library is not present on an emulator. If you only plan to work with web services, APIs', GUIs' then I suppose an emulator is more than sufficient. Unlike the iOS *simulator*, an Android emulator generally exhibits the WYSIWYG behavior, so your GUI will not differ on actual devices, although you do need to test your GUI on multiple AVDs' with different screen form factors.

Comment: @shortstheory: have you seen this ?

Comment: thank you for the answer! But I have (in my opinion) a fast computer: an i5-3230M with 4GB RAM. Would the slowness of an emulator really be such an issue?

Comment: Please see the edit too, I have a few more questions.

Comment: My CPU indeed supports vtx, so the emulator should run well. Thank you!

Comment: out of curiosity, what is the upvote/downvote count on this question? I don't have enough rep to check it myself, but I'm gaining rep without the number of votes increasing on this question strangely.

Comment: its +1 and -1 ... so you might have gained 3 points for that. Sometimes people seem to downvote and close questions that are real, valid problems for the OP, I just visited another question where the OP threatened to report the downvoters ... I shall upvote you.